# Determine $\overline{Y}$

Tags: general-topology

Hello I don't know how to $\overline{Y}$

Let $X= \prod_{1}^\infty  \mathbb{R}$ and $Y= \{ \prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i \in X : a_i \neq 0$ only for finite quantity of  $i \} $ Determine $\overline{Y}$

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?  Understand the topology of $X$.

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: I think you mean that $Y = \{a \in X : a_i \neq 0 \mbox{ for only finitely many }i\}$. Is that right?

Comment: If $B$ is a basic open set in the product, is it possible that $B\cap Y=\varnothing$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base $B$ for the (Tychonoff) product topology on $X$ is the family of all sets of the form $\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}U_i$ such that (i) each $U_i$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and (ii) the set $\{i:U_i\ne \Bbb R\}$ is finite.

If $ V$ is a non-empty open subset of $X,$ take some $x=(x_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}\in V,$ and take some   $U=\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}U_i\in B$ with $x\in U\subset V.$

Then $x_i\in U_i$ for every $i.$

Now let $C=\{i: U_i\ne \Bbb R\}.$ For $i\in C$ let $y_i=x_i.$ For $i\in \Bbb N\setminus C$ let $y_i=0.$

Then $y_i\in U_i$ for every $i,$ so $y=^{def} (y_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}\in \prod_{i\in\Bbb N}U_i=U\subset V.$

And also $y\in Y$ because $C$ is finite.

So $y\in V\cap Y$.

So since $Y$ has non-empty intersection with every non-empty open $V$ of the space $X,$ we have $\overline Y=X.$

Answer (score 0):

The topology on $X$ is the *product topology*. A basis consists in the sets of the form  $\prod_{i=1}^\infty U_i $ where all but finitely many $U_i=\mathbb R$.

Now any such open set intersects $Y$. Because each of the  $U_i $ such that $U_i=\mathbb R $ contains zero.

Thus the only closed set containing  $Y $ is $X$.  That's  $Y $ is *dense*.